# Consulta a multitabla SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No estoy muy familiarizado con el uso de las consultas de este tipo y no logro entender como realizar el ejercicio siguiente:

> "Escribir la consulta que permita Listar las 5 provincias con más estaciones."

Desde ya muchas gracias

Comment: @Aprendiz No veo nada malo en mostrar el modelo de datos en una imagen. No quita que no sería bueno que pusiera datos de ejemplo, pero con lo que hay, puede ser contestada perfectamente

Comment: cierto @Lamak quitaré el primer comentario solo dejando la última recomendación que agregue su intento aunque este contenga errores

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu consulta es relativamente simple. Viendo el diagrama de datos, podemos ver que la relación es **"una provincia puede tener varias ciudades y una ciudad puede tener varias estaciones"**...de la misma forma **"una estación pertenece a una única ciudad, una ciudad pertenece a una única provincia"**.

Ahora, lo más simple de hacer en tu caso, es utilizar un `INNER JOIN` entre esas 3 tablas, y luego hacer un `COUNT`.

```
SELECT  TOP 5 
            p.idprovincias,
            p.nombre Provincia,
            COUNT(*) Estaciones
FROM dbo.provincias p
INNER JOIN dbo.ciudades c
    ON p.idprovincias = c.idprovincia
INNER JOIN dbo.estacion e
    ON c.idciudad = e.idciudad
GROUP BY p.idprovincias,
         p.nombre
ORDER BY Estaciones DESC
;
```

La consulta anterior te va a entregar hasta 5 provincias, ordenadas de la que tiene mayor cantidad de estaciones a la menor. Sin embargo, también podrías querer considerar el caso en que por ejemplo, la quinta y sexta provincia tengan la misma cantidad de estaciones. Con la consulta anterior, se va a quedar con una de ellas (y como no hay segundo criterio de ordenación, va a usar un orden arbitrario).

Si quisieras que en caso de empate, te muestre esas provincias empatadas, puedes usar `WITH TIES` después del `TOP`:

```
SELECT  TOP 5 WITH TIES
            p.idprovincias,
            p.nombre Provincia,
            COUNT(*) Estaciones
FROM dbo.provincias p
INNER JOIN dbo.ciudades c
    ON p.idprovincias = c.idprovincia
INNER JOIN dbo.estacion e
    ON c.idciudad = e.idciudad
GROUP BY p.idprovincias,
         p.nombre
ORDER BY Estaciones DESC
;
```